# Sequence of consecutive gaps in prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_i$ be $i^{th}$ prime number (for example $p_4=7$). Is there $m=m(n, k)$ such that $n \leq \min \{p_{m+i}-p_{m+i-1} : 1 \leq i \leq k\}$ for every $n$ and $k$? Even, consider the problem for $k=2$.

Comment: For $k=1$, $a!+2, a!+3, ..., a!+a$ make an arbitrary large gap, when $a$ is an arbitrary large number.

Comment: This is a consequence of the prime k-tuples conjecture.  Based on recent work involving k=2 (Tao, Pintz, Maynard and others) it is likely that m will be exponential in n and k. Gerhard "A Prime Time For Mathematics" Paseman, 2016.12.03.

Comment: AFAIK, the OP is asking whether there are arbitrarily long run of arbitrarily large prime gaps, which is not exactly the question the above comments are answering.

Comment: I am sure that there was a good intention but to me, this question does not make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński: The question makes full sense. As Fan Zheng remarked, it can be reformulated in plain English as: are there arbitrarily long runs of arbitrarily large prime gaps? Then answer is yes, see my response.

Comment: I answered your question in the positive (see below). Please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was proved in a strong quantitative form by Maier in his paper Chains of large gaps between consecutive primes, Adv. in Math. 39 (1981), 257-269. Recently, Pintz strengthened this result with Maynard's method, see Theorem 4' in [this arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2213).